# Trying to get two postman.setNextRequest (not chained) or two Actions in Workspace

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script, postman-testcase, postman-native-app

I’m quite new to postman (and coding) and was trying to find and piece together many snippets of scripts to make it work the way I want.
What I want is very simple: I have a list of IDs that I want to make a POST in each of them, get one of the responseBody as a variable and do another POST. I think I’m close but I can’t manage to get it to work.

I’ve tried:
Two POST request in the same Collection and running the collection.
In the first request I have a POST to

https://APIADDRESS/?order_id{{orderid}}&contract[copy_order_data]=true

**On the Pre-request Script tab:**

```
var orderids = pm.environment.get(“orderids”);

if (!orderids) {
orderids = [“bc46bf79-2846-44ed-ac4d-78c77c92ccc8”,“81aacc33-1ade-41a3-b23e-06b03b526b8f”];
}

var currentOrderId = orderids.shift();
pm.environment.set(“orderid”, currentOrderId);
pm.environment.set(“orderids”, orderids);
```

**On the Tests tab:**

```
var orderids = pm.environment.get(“orderids”);

if (orderids && orderids.length > 0) {
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable(“invoice.id”, jsonData.invoice.id);
postman.setNextRequest(“Create invoice”);
} else {
postman.setNextRequest(null);

}
```

invoice.id is a environment variable populated with the response body of the first action/post and then using the variable on the second action/post.

And then the second request would be a POST to

https://APIADDRESS/invoices/{{invoice.id}}/finalize.json

Of course this doesn’t work. Either it doesn't run the second request in the collection or it doesn't do the loope to more than 1 ID on the list.

So I thought that putting the second POST inside the first one would solve it. But I had no luck.

Can please someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried mentioned use case with sample API's provided by POSTMAN.
Can you try it?

**First POST Method Request** : https://postman-echo.com/post

**Pre-request Script of first POST method**

```
var orderids  = pm.environment.get("orderids");

if(!orderids ){
    orderids = ["bc46bf79-2846-44ed-ac4d-78c77c92ccc8","81aacc33-1ade-41a3-b23e-06b03b526b8f"];
}

var currentOrderId = orderids.shift();
pm.environment.set("orderid", currentOrderId);
pm.environment.set("orderids", orderids);
```

**Tests Tab of first POST Method**

```
var orderids = pm.environment.get("orderids");
if (orderids && orderids.length > 0) {
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("invoice.id", jsonData.headers.host);
postman.setNextRequest("Test1");
} else {
postman.setNextRequest(null);
}
```

**Second POST Method Reqeust**: https://postman-echo.com/post?key={{invoice.id}}

After executing the above collection it will set orederids and invoice.id value in environment variables and then it will call next POST Method.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @HalfBloodPrince, from the Postman Echo it worked but in my case it doesn't :S
What I manage to get it working was using a Json file as a list of Orderids.
In that  case I've separated all requests.

**Request1 - https://APIADDRESS/?order_id{{orderid}}&contract[copy_order_data]=true**

**Tests tab:**

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("invoice.id", jsonData.invoice.id);
```

**Request2 - https://APIADDRESS/invoices/{{invoice.id}}/finalize.json**

That way everything is in a neat and organized way.
Thanks